# How to get last year's same week data in SOLR

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

How do I get last years same week data?

I used `fq=trans_date:[NOW-1YEAR/DAY-7DAY TO NOW-1YEAR/DAY]` on date field which will give me last 7 days data for last year. But that approach doesn't take into account calender weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easier to calculate the boundaries for your week number last year in the frontend and then query Solr with the date interval. That way you can get the behavior you want regarding sundays/mondays as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not provide a nice way to do this. 
It would be really cool if you could do `fq=trans_date:[NOW-1YEAR/WEEK TO NOW-1YEAR/WEEK]` but this is not supported.

Nevertheless, you could create a quick function using php or javascript using each language's native Date operators and get the Week number from today to produce start and end points to feed solr in a query like `[1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z TO 2007-03-06T00:00:00Z]`.